# Regex custom form validation matching words inside "[hello.world]"

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm practicing form validation by creating my own jquery plugin and regex. I have the following strings:

```
required
email|test_validation[key.val]
required|email
required|custom_validation
```

**I want to get the following strings:**

```
[required, email, test_validation[key.val], required,email, required, custom_validation
```

**and here is my regex:**

```
/(\w+(\[\w+\])?)[^|]/g
```

But the problem is it's only capturing all the words, and treats test_validation[key.val] as separate words where it's supposed to be 1 word.

Comment: `\w` stands for `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. It does not include `.`, so `hello.world` is broken down to two pieces by the dot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make your regex simpler, you can capture more like so:

```
/([^|\s]+)/gm
```

Result:

[image: regex]

Matches all from

```
[required, email, test_validation[key.val], required,email, required, custom_validation]
```

[image: matches]

### Demo: [http://jsbin.com/sejuloqudo/1/](http://jsbin.com/sejuloqudo/1/watch?js,console)

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the dot present inside the `[key.val]`, since `\w` won't match the dot. So replace `\[\w+\]` with `\[[\w.]+\]` or use like below

```
/(\w+(\[[^\[\]]*\])?)(?=\||$)/g
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nZ4nR2/1)

And also no need to go fro capturing groups.

```
\w+(?:\[[\w.]+\])?(?=\||$)
```

Positive lookahead `(?=\||$)` asserts that the match must be followed by `|` or end of the line boundary.

Comment: if ever I need more strict conditions I will use your method. thanks! helped me alot